# Is there any way to show videos in uiimagepicker filtered by created date?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

User will enter a date in text box. After that he will click on a button to select videos from his phone album. Then using uiimagepicker user will pick videos from phone album.

What I want is that the uiimagepicker only needs to show videos created on the date he entered in the text box. Is there anyway to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create custom `UIImagePicker` using `ALAsset`